# Implementation of Webhook receiver

Tags: .net-core, webhooks, .net-6.0, .net-5

I am trying to create webhook receiver using .Net 5.

But the Nuget Package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Webhooks.Receivers.Custom** appears to be depreciated.
Is there any alternative Nuget package which works on .Net 5/.Net 6?

Which template is better for webhook receiver implementation (like MVC,Web API,Console etc)?

Any supporting links for implementation of webhook receiver using .Net 5/.Net 6 will be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't find the webhook support in ASP.net core 5/6. I came up with another option as **ASP.NET Core SignalR**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Check if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Webhook receiver is just a post endpoint, so something like this should do it. Or you can find some useful extension here https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/WebHooks

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task MyWebHookEndpoint()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        
    }
}
```